# Testing AJAX/XMLHttpRequest pages functionally in Symfony2

Tags: ajax, testing, symfony

Is it possible to simulate/make an XMLHttpRequest request (ajax) in symfony2 tests?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

After search with "Problematic" answer, the correct syntax is:

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/foo/', array(), array(), array(
    'HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
));
```

Answer (score 6):

The `Request#isXmlHttpRequest()` method simply checks if the `X-Requested-With` header is equivalent to `XMLHttpRequest`. If that's the method you're using to determine if a request is an ajax call, then you can simulate the behavior in the test client by adding the appropriate header to the request:

```
class FooFunctionalTest extends WebTestCase
{
    $client = static::CreateClient();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/foo/', array(), array(), array(
        'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
    ));
    // ...
}
```

More information can be found about the Request object [in the source code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L1160).

Comment: syntax problem, see my answer. Thank's =)

Answer (score 2):

For `POST`, `PUT`:

```
$crawler = $client->request('POST', '/foo/', array('param' => 'value'), array(),
array(
    'HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
));
```

For `POST`, `PUT` with raw `JSON` body:

```
$crawler = $client->request('POST', '/foo/', array(), array(), array(
    'HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json',
), '{"param": "value"}');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with Symfony 3.x or 4.x this is the correct way to do it using POST method.

```
$data = ['some' => 'value'];
$client = static::createClient();
$client->request('POST', '/some_uri', ['data' => $data], [],; [
  'HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
]);
```