# submit a form using ajax in functional test

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, phpunit, functional-testing

I'm creating a functional test for the inscription part of my project and I need to know how to test it if the form needs to go in an ajax request, otherwise the server will always return an empty inscription form.

Looks like the submit method doesn't take an argument that specifies whether it's an ajax a request unlike request method ->  http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Client.html#method_submit

Thanks

**UPDATE1**

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////
// My functional test looks exactly like this //
////////////////////////////////////////////////
$form = $buttonCrawlerNode->form(array(
    'name'              => 'Fabien',
    'my_form[subject]'  => 'Symfony rocks!',
));
// There is no way here I can tell client to submit using ajax!!!!
$client->submit($form);

// Why can't we tell client to submit using ajax???
// Like we do here in the request méthod
$client->request(
    'GET',
    '/post/hello-world',
    array(),
    array(),
    array('HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest')
);
```

Comment: Can you provide your codes of tested subject and unit test?

Comment: you could do a POST (first argument) and pass the underlying data as array (third argument). what problem do you see in this?

Comment: i edit my answer, hope this is more clear

Comment: possible duplicate of [Testing AJAX/XMLHttpRequest pages functionally in Symfony2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400233/testing-ajax-xmlhttprequest-pages-functionally-in-symfony2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Symfony [Request Object intercept an XmlHttpRequest](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L1732) in the header of the request. So simply add the correct header to your request in the test class, as example:

```
class FooFunctionalTest extends WebTestCase
{
    $client = static::CreateClient();
    $url = '/post/hello-world';
    // makes the POST request
    $crawler = $client->request('POST', $url, array(
        'my_form' => array(
            'subject' => 'Symfony rocks!'
        )),
        array(),
        array(
            'HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
        )
    );
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: I've updated my post, can I add in the header through the méthod submit? please have a look at the comments of update1 of my post

Comment: So you confirm that we cannot take advantage of `client->submit($form)` which take care of cookies and everything. **Conclusion** to send a form using ajax, submit méthod of Client cannot do it, so we got to use the classic request. Thx Matteo

Comment: @smarber actually you can take advantage of client->submit($form). See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a way to take advantage of `Client::submit` but you need to create new Client instance if you want to do non-ajax requests after that (for now, see GitHub issue link below).

```
$client->setServerParameter('HTTP_X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
$client->submit($form);

// The following method doesn't exist yet.
// @see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/20306
// If this method gets added then you won't need to create
// new Client instances for following non-ajax requests,
// you can just do this:
// $client->unsetServerParameter('HTTP_X-Requested-With');
```